ASRock UEFI doesn't recognize GPT partitions without CSM
tl;dr
My ASRock computer is unable to boot my Gentoo Linux system, which resides on its only drive, which is formatted with GPT. When CSM is disabled in the UEFI, no boot entries show up and I always loop back into UEFI. When CSM is enabled, my hard drive shows up (without any partitions), but cannot boot ("reboot and select proper boot device"), I assume because it thinks the drive is MBR but it's not, so it can't boot it using legacy BIOS.
Background
A while ago my bootloader (grub2) broke, but the error seemed to be quite common and possibly resolvable by updating grub. Now that I got around to trying to fix it, I booted a live linux usb drive, mounted the original file system, chrooted, and updated grub. That all went fine, until I tried grub-install (this might be relevant): It said "EFI variables are not supported on this system". Some research suggested that this might be a problem when you boot your live distro with BIOS instead of UEFI. Some troubleshooting later I ended up re-flashing my USB with GPT instead of MBR, but that actually made it not boot anymore ("Error: BIOS/Legacy Boot of UEFI-only Media" by Rufus). It did boot after I disabled CSM in the UEFI, though. Then, I managed to grub-install and grub-mkconfig just fine.
Now probably the weirdest part is that after this, I turned off the system, unplugged the live USB. When booting back up, everything worked perfectly. GRUB loaded fine, and I was able to boot into Gentoo without issues (so I actually fixed my grub installation). But then I decided to reboot again, and ended up where I am now:

When CSM is disabled in the UEFI, not a single boot record shows up, and I can only ever access the UEFI or the boot menu. I can still boot the live USB when it's plugged in, but only when CSM is disabled
When CSM is enabled, one boot record shows up in UEFI, but it's just the drive itself and no partitions. Trying to boot the drive gives me the "reboot and select proper boot device" error.

To me it seems like for some reason, UEFI thinks my drive is formatted in MBR (hence it not showing up when CSM is disabled), but when it actually tries to boot it using legacy BIOS, it cannot do so because it's GPT formatted.
Update
After comments from @daniel-b and @grawity-u1686 I investigated further and tried some additional things. First, I checked with efibootmgr which boot entries are already present. Indeed, the grub entry was missing.
Another thing I tried was re-execute grub-mkconfig which says in its logs that it adds boot entries, but there was still nothing there afterwards.
I decided to add the entry manually using efibootmgr, so I inspected my efi partition layout (mounted at /boot):
/boot
├── amd-uc.img
├── config-6.6.21-gentoo(.old)
├── initramfs-6.6.21-gentoo.img
├── intel-uc.img
├── System.map-6.6.21-gentoo(.old)
├── vmlinuz-6.6.21-gentoo(.old)
├── /EFI
│   └── /gentoo
│       └── grubx64.efi
└── /grub
    ├── grub.cfg
    ├── grubenv
    ├── /fonts [...]
    ├── /themes [...]
    └── /x86_64-efi [...]

Seems a bit weird to me, but anyway, I then executed the following efibootmgr command:
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L "Grub" -l '\boot\EFI\gentoo\grubx64.efi'

This entry does now show up in UEFI, but it can't boot (just loops right back to UEFI, I didn't find any error message). Did I do anything wrong with this command?
Additional Data

The UEFI version is "N3000-NUC P1.30"
I'm trying to boot Gentoo Linux
The live USB distro is SystemRescue 11.02
I have confirmed via GParted that the disk is partitioned using GPT, and that /dev/sda1 is the boot partition, formatted with fat32


UEFI booting relies on boot entries in NVRAM ("EFI variables"). Check them, for example using efibootmgr. The bootx64.efi fallback logic sometimes only works on removable devices.

could it be that I need to reconfigure the boot entries using efibootmgr as described here? https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr

Possibly; does it currently show your GRUB boot entry? With the correct PARTUUID? Does your EFI partition contain the aforementioned fallback bootx64.efi file?

@grawity_u1686 updated to answer your questions


To me it seems like for some reason, UEFI thinks my drive is formatted in MBR (hence it not showing up when CSM is disabled), but when it actually tries to boot it using legacy BIOS, it cannot do so because it's GPT formatted.

That's not how it works. GPT partitioning and BIOS boot-code are not mutually exclusive – in fact every GPT partitioned disk is required to have a "protective" MBR alongside, and that MBR can contain legacy BIOS code that understands GPT partitioning. (And vice versa, MBR-partitioned disks can have an EFI System Partition for UEFI boot.)
Which means that in CSM mode, more-or-less any disk will show up, even if it has no legacy boot code (but it could just as well have stale boot code from two reinstalls ago).
The actual reason your disk doesn't show up as an UEFI-bootable disk is:

Per specification, internal (fixed) disks aren't supposed to show up at all, as the whole concept of a "bootable disk" in EFI only exists for removable disks – USB sticks, CDs, and such – while internal disks aren't meant to be bootable in themselves.
Instead of booting an internal disk, you're meant to boot an OS from within that disk, via custom OS boot entries (such as the one you've added via efibootmgr) that point directly to a specific boot file.

Practically speaking, most firmwares don't actually care about the "internal vs removable" distinction and will indeed show internal disks as bootable – as long as they have the right contents.
So your disk doesn't show up because it does not have the bootloader installed at \EFI\boot\bootx64.efi, which is the "default" location for an EFI loader. When boot entries are not present, the firmware will not scan a disk's EFI partition for just any .efi file – it only looks for that specific file.


So you have two ways to make UEFI recognize an internal disk as bootable: a) add a custom entry via efibootmgr or b) install the bootloader (GRUB) at the default removable path. Preferably the former, as the latter will get out of sync with the main copy if done manually.

This entry does now show up in UEFI, but it can't boot (just loops right back to UEFI, I didn't find any error message). Did I do anything wrong with this command?

EFI boot entry paths are relative to the root of the EFI partition – not to the Linux filesystem root, as EFI is completely unaware of your Linux mount arrangement. The EFI path to your grubx64.efi would therefore be \EFI\gentoo\grubx64.efi.

thank you! that's a lot of helpful information and the last part actually fixed my problem. I'm also 95% sure what caused my boot entries to disappear, because it happened again. My BIOS battery has been empty since I started using this computer, indicated by the time resetting whenever the machine is unplugged. Now however, it seems like the boot entries vanish as well when I unplug. No idea why that wasn't the case earlier though..
